# Buscar con procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Buen día compañeros tengo un procedimiento almacenado para buscar por código y funciona bien pero quisiera saber si hay una manera de que al buscar por ejemplo el 1.5 ademas de buscar los que tengan el 1.5 también arrastre el registro con código 1 y si se pone 2.1 que arrastre el registro 2, y que si busca por cods tambien los encuentre de la misma forma.

```
codp   cods
1      rxx
2      rxx    
1.5    r01              
1.5    r01
1.6    r02      
2.1    r23      
2.1    r23          
2.1    r23


create procedure buscar
@codp float
as begin
set nocount on
select * from codigos
where @codp=codp
end
```

Comment: y si busco el 1.6 qué resultado debería entregar?

Comment: el registro del 1.6 y el del 1

Comment: Es decir que lo que buscas es redondear hacia el menor, es decir, que te de siempre el numero entero, quitando el decimal para decirlo de alguna forma.

Comment: si es eso basicamente y si hay alguna forma de que si me busca por ejemplo ya no por codp si no por cods  encuentre los mismo resultados

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según tu comentario, lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
SELECT *
FROM codigos
WHERE codp = @codp 
OR codp = FLOOR(@codp);
```

Comment: Gracias compañero funciono bien disculpa  hay alguna forma de que si me busca por ejemplo ya no por codp si no por cods encuentre los mismo resultados pero que este en el mismo store?

Comment: es un poco más complicado porque son columnas con tipos de datos diferentes...

Comment: bueno no soy experto en esto apenas tengo unos cuantos dias con sql server pero puede haber alguna forma de que aunque el ponga por ejemplo r23 enrealidad lo que haga sea la busqueda por codp