# Actualizar campo con una condicion especifica con trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, trigger, tsql

Tengo la siguiente situacion quisiera una idea de la condicion que podria poner digamos en un trigger para que  cuando inserte un ISR422 por ejmplo 1.1 se actualice la fecha automaticamente del que tiene un isr422=1 , es decir, ambos tendrian las misma fecha en el campo date,puedo seguir insertando registros que tenga un ISR422 =1.2, 1.3 etcetera pero quiero que se actualice  exclusivamente cuando en su punto decimal sea .1. Hasta ahora no se me ocurre cualquier idea que puedan tener.

```
id_product  product     ISR422           date
1           dr43        1               20/07/17                
2           fh28        4       
3           sd43        2               
4           fh28        3   
5           fh29        1.1             20/07/17
6           dr43        4.1
```

Comment: Hola Eruska6, Esta [otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83877/buscar-con-procedimiento-almacenado/83884#83884) seguramente te va a ayudar.

Comment: Nunca he usado floor cual o como  seria la condicion que podria poner en el trigger?

Comment: El `floor` te de devuelve el entero máximo menor o igual al indicado, es decir `floor(1.1)  = 1`. Consultas: si actualizan el 1.3 hay que actualizar tanto el 1, como el 1.1, 1.2 y, 1.3? Si actualizan el 1 también hay que actualizar el resto?

Comment: No compañero @PatricioMoracho solo si tengo un numero entero el 1 y despues de un tiempo se ingresa un registro con ISR422 =1.1 se actualiza la fecha del que tenga ISR422=1 y si por ejemplo tengo un ISR422=2 el unico que puede actualizar su fecha seria cuando se ingresara un registro con ISR422=2.1

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentalmente lo que pides es cuando se actualice la fecha de un registro cuya columna ISR422 tenga un valor del tipo [numero].1 se actualice además el registro cuya valor para esa columna sea [numero].

Vamos a usar la función [`PARSENAME`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql), Disponible desde SQL 2012, espero sea compatible con tu versión. Sino hay que buscar otra alternativa. Básicamente esta rutina, permite obtener las partes de un objeto con el punto como separador, veamos unos ejemplos:

```
SELECT 'PARSENAME(4.1, 1)', PARSENAME(4.1, 1) UNION
SELECT 'PARSENAME(4.1, 2)', PARSENAME(4.1, 2) UNION
SELECT 'PARSENAME(3.4, 1)', PARSENAME(3.4, 1) UNION
SELECT 'PARSENAME(3.4, 2)', PARSENAME(3.4, 2) UNION
SELECT 'PARSENAME(1, 1)', PARSENAME(1, 1) UNION
SELECT 'PARSENAME(1, 2)', PARSENAME(1, 2)
```

El resultado:

```
================ =====
PARSENAME(1, 1)      1
PARSENAME(1, 2)   NULL
PARSENAME(3.4, 1)    4
PARSENAME(3.4, 2)    3
PARSENAME(4.1, 1)    1
PARSENAME(4.1, 2)    4
```

Como se ven en lo ejemplos, vamos a usar esta función, para determinar el registro "padre" y también si el valor actualizado tiene el valor decimal indicado.

En primer lugar, a modo de ejemplo, creamos una tabla de prueba:

```
CREATE TABLE Ejemplo (
    id_product  INT,
    product     VARCHAR(15),
    ISR422      FLOAT,
    date        DATETIME
)
GO
```

Y definimos el trigger de `UPDATE` (uno de `INSERT` es muy similar)

```
CREATE TRIGGER U_Ejemplo ON dbo.Ejemplo AFTER UPDATE
AS

    IF ((SELECT TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()) < 2)
    BEGIN
        IF UPDATE(date)
        BEGIN
            -- Si se actualizo un 1.1 actualizamos también 1
            UPDATE Ejemplo
                SET date = I.date
                FROM Ejemplo T
                INNER JOIN INSERTED I
                    ON  T.ISR422 = PARSENAME(I.ISR422,2) -- Actualizamos el id sin parte decimal
                        AND PARSENAME(I.ISR422,1) = 1 -- Solo si la parte decimal del que hemos actualizado es .1
        END
    END

GO
```

Agregamos algunos ejemplos a la tabla

```
INSERT INTO Ejemplo(id_product, product, ISR422)
   VALUES (1, 'dr43', 1),
          (2, 'fh28', 4),
          (3, 'sd43', 2),
          (4, 'fh28', 3),
          (5, 'fh29', 1.1),
          (6, 'fh29', 1.2),
          (7, 'dr43', 4.1)
```

Si verificamos el funcionamiento por ejemplo actualizando el ISR422 = 1.1 por el `id_product`.

```
UPDATE Ejemplo
    SET date = '20170720'
    WHERE id_product = 5

SELECT *
       FROM Ejemplo
```

Y el resultado final

```
==== ======= ======= ===========================
1,00    dr43    1,00    20/07/2017 12:00:00 a.m. <- Actualizado
2,00    fh28    4,00    NULL
3,00    sd43    2,00    NULL
4,00    fh28    3,00    NULL
5,00    fh29    1,10    20/07/2017 12:00:00 a.m. <- Actualizado
6,00    fh29    1,11    NULL
7,00    dr43    4,10    NULL
```

Además, en caso de actualizar otro valor, por ejemplo 1.11, solo debiera actualizarse el mismo y no el "padre"

```
UPDATE Ejemplo
    SET date = '20170722'
    WHERE id_product = 6
```

Vemos que efectivamente es así

```
==== ======= ======= ===========================
1,00    dr43    1,00    20/07/2017 12:00:00 a.m.
2,00    fh28    4,00    NULL
3,00    sd43    2,00    NULL
4,00    fh28    3,00    NULL
5,00    fh29    1,10    20/07/2017 12:00:00 a.m.
6,00    fh29    1,11    22/07/2017 12:00:00 a.m. <- Solo se actualizo este registro
7,00    dr43    4,10    NULL
```

Notas adicionales

- No especificaste el tipo de dato de esta columna, `FLOAT, DECIMAL` ni eventualmente la precisión, no vamos a contemplar casos como `1.1000001` de última se puede redondear a un decimal para que siga funcionando el algoritmo propuesto.
- El `TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()` lo usamos ya que estamos actualizando sobre la misma tabla, hay que contemplar esto para evitar un encadenamiento de triggers.